# Parity of number of digits

Tags: exponentiation, decimal-expansion

Let $s(n)$ be the number of digits of $n$. Prove that $s(4^{2017}) + s(25^{2017})$ is odd. A solution without using logarithms would be nice.

Comment: $s(4^{2017}) + s(25^{2017})=s(100^{2017})=2\cdot 2017+1=4035$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product of $4^{2017}$ and $25^{2017}$ is $100^{2017}$. We can write
$4^{2017}=10^ra$ and $25^{2017}=10^sb$ where $1<a,b<10$. Then
$4^{2017}$ has $r+1$ digits and $25^{2017}$ has $s+1$ digits. But $ab=10$
and $r+s=4033$, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate  $[2017\log25]+1=2820$ and $[2017\log4]+1=1215$.

Comment: How do you know that $s(4^{2017})$ is even?

Comment: @problembuster  I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: Thanks! Nice one!

Comment: @problembuster Welcome!